# How to convert python list of tf.Tensors (of variable length) to tf.Tensor of the tensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a python list of tensorflow tensors. These tensors are of variable length. An example of one is:

```
tf.Tensor(
[-5.6968699e-04 -1.8224530e-03  1.9018153e-04  2.4998413e-05
  5.7804082e-06  9.0757676e-04  1.7357236e-03  3.7930862e-04
 -1.1174149e-03  9.7289361e-04  1.3030922e-03  4.9432577e-04
 -7.0594731e-05 -1.9857733e-04  8.9881440e-05  3.3402088e-04
  9.7116083e-04  5.0820946e-04 -2.0063705e-04 -3.1353189e-03
 -2.9622321e-03  2.9554308e-04 -1.1153796e-03  9.8816957e-04
 -4.6766747e-04 -2.7386995e-04 -5.6890573e-04  3.5687000e-03
 -1.3535956e-03  4.5281884e-04 -3.5806431e-04 -8.6313725e-04
 -6.7768141e-04  2.2069726e-05 -4.3477840e-04 -1.5338012e-03
 -2.7985810e-03 -1.4244686e-03  6.5509509e-04 -1.2790617e-04
  1.1837900e-03 -5.8377518e-05 -6.3234463e-04  1.7508399e-03
  2.9831685e-04 -2.2373318e-04 -2.8749602e-04  1.7911429e-03
 -3.7155824e-04  1.2438967e-03  8.0730570e-05  1.0137054e-03
 -2.6455871e-04 -7.6767977e-04 -1.1590059e-03  9.9610852e-04
 -1.9824551e-04 -2.7367761e-03  6.6492974e-04 -1.3874021e-03
  2.5623629e-04 -1.7116729e-03 -1.4603567e-04  2.9647996e-04], shape=(64,), dtype=float32)
```

But not all of these tensors have the same dimensionality so I can't use tf.convert_to_tensor() without getting an error

```
'Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [8,8,4,32] != values[1].shape = [32] [Op:Pack] name: packed'
```

How can I convert this list of tf.Tensors to a tf.Tensor of tf.Tensors.

The reason I want to do this is as follows:

In my code I am calling the Adam optimizer as follows:

```
self.dqn_architecture.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(dqn_architecture_grads, traibnable_vars))
```

But I noticed the following showing up in my logs:

```
2023-02-17 20:05:44,776 5 out of the last 5 calls to <function _BaseOptimizer._update_step_xla at 0x7f55421ab6d0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
2023-02-17 20:05:44,822 6 out of the last 6 calls to <function _BaseOptimizer._update_step_xla at 0x7f55421ab6d0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
```

On further investigation I found that I am passing python lists of tensors to the optimizer as opposed to tensors of tensors i.e. (3)

I’ve also noticed that there seems to be a memory leak as my RAM usage continues to grow the more I train the model. This makes sense because on stackoverflow I read that:

```
'Passing python scalars or lists as arguments to tf.function will always build a new graph. To avoid this, pass numeric arguments as Tensors whenever possible'
```

So, I believe the solution would be to pass a tensor of these tensors as opposed to a list. But, on trying to convert the lists to tensors using tf.convert_to_tensor(), I get the error:

```
'Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [8,8,4,32] != values[1].shape = [32] [Op:Pack] name: packed'
```

because the tensors have varying dimensionality.

I tried using tf.ragged.constant too. But also got the error:

```
raise ValueError("all scalar values must have the same nesting depth")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Really need to get this sorted. :)

Comment: You cant, tensors must have the same shape, and each dimension has a specific meaning. Why not to keep them in an array. The only way you can is when they have the N-1 same dimensions, in which case you can concatenate them, like a matrix of 1x2 and 2x2 to give 3x2

Answer (score 1):

Actually this method `tf.convert_to_tensor()` is used when the shapes of all the matrices are the same. But in your case each tensor has a different shape. So, for that **Tensorflow** has introduced new kind of **Tensors** which enclose different shapes of **Tensors** as one **Tensor**, known as **`Ragged Tensors`**. Now, lets do the example for your case.

```
# create a list of variable-length tensors
tensors = [
    tf.constant([1, 2, 3]),
    tf.constant([4, 5]),
    tf.constant([6, 7, 8, 9]),
]

#Now I have to stack the tensors
ragged_tensors  = tf.ragged.stack(tensors)
```

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]>
```

Now, above did you see that the size of each tensor is different, but if you want this **`Ragged Tensor`** to become your normal **Tensor** then just use **`ragged_tensors.to_tensor()`** method, and your different sized **Tensor** will become a **normal tensor**.

```
ragged_tensors.to_tensor()
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 4), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [4, 5, 0, 0],
       [6, 7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. It's appreciated. Unfortunately, I can't use ragged.constant either because 'all scalar values must have the same nesting depth'. I edited the question to add further detail and would be grateful for any further help you can offer. :)

Comment: use `tf.ragged.stack()` function not `constant`. Have you tried this?

Comment: One thing more your list of the list should have the same level of nestings. By level of nesting, I mean they all should be of the same rank. Otherwise, it will fail to work.

Comment: Can you tell me the shapes of your tensors in a list?

Comment: As of now, I'm not 100% sure it's number 3 that's actually causing the problem. Thanks for the help so far. I'm going to keep looking into it and update here when I find the problem.